# Geofencing limit with Android

Tags: android, limit, android-geofence

So I've been looking into Geofencing. We wan't to use it to limit the use of an application to a certain location. Android developers states this:

"You can have multiple active geofences, with a limit of 100 per device user."

As it states here, the geofencing is device bound. So if I distribute my app to 100 people, they can all use 100 Geofencing locations. That would be 100 * 100 = 10.000 geofencing locations. Am I correct here? Or is it limited to an application? So these 100 users can only use 100 geofencing locations.

And if it is app limited, does a different flavour get another 100 locations? So 3 flavours would then result in 300 locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a single user device the limit is 100 per app.

On a multi-user device (i.e. post Lollipop) each USER can have their own defined 100 Geofencing locations. Therefore, as each of the users can have their own 100 locations then, yes, there can be 10,000 locations as you say. But each user is limited to 'their' 100.

If you want to use more than 100 you could record coordinates elsewhere (for example in a SQLite database) and then, say, load the nearest 100 (by calculating distance to each one from your current location) and then rotate them accordingly. But the app can only process 100 at a time.

[I would suggest the reasoning for this limit is the processing overhead involved with polling multiple locations every few minutes]